# Could some interfaces in java.sql and javax.sql be re-used for NoSQL?

Tags: java, sql, nosql

[Other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208821/strategic-issue-mixing-relational-and-non-relational-db) folks have asked about using SQL and NoSQL together, and [subsequently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270945/spring-and-mixing-sql-and-nosql-db) whether there's a clean way of defining the access objects in a clean, generic way.

My question is somewhat related -- which parts of java.sql and javax.sql can be re-used, and is there any plan for **Oracle*** to get into the NoSQL space and hopefully provide an API? I know that [the various NoSQL options differ quite a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247036/is-there-a-nosql-key-value-store-abstraction-library-like-there-is-jdbc-is-for), hence having a "JDBC" doesn't seem to make sense.

PS I like what David Pollack is doing for Lift with [Record](http://main.scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.1/framework/scaladocs/net/liftweb/record/Record.scala.html) and [DBRecord](http://main.scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.1/framework/scaladocs/net/liftweb/record/DBRecord.scala.html).

***** That's Oracle-who-now-owns-Java, not Oracle-the-database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, each NoSQL engine (Cassandra, Neo4J, HBase, etc.) provides its own access API. Theses APIs are not unified, and are absolutely not based on "java.sql" nor "javax.sql".

So, now, I think it makes no sense to try using theses packages with NoSQL databases. But I'm hoping for a unification of theses products with a common API (and/or query language) by category (column-oriented, graph, document databases for example).